# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using a material navigation drawer in my android project using Xamarin.
I have been trying to add two Framelayouts into the drawerlayout so that I can switch the content from different fragments see below xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
      <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview">
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/blah"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
          </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
      </LinearLayout>
      <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
      <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
      <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
          android:id="@+id/nav_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
          app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
          app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
          android:background="#464646"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The main activity :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Android_OS.Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
    // Setting up the toolbar
    var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.ApplicationName);
    SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // Attach item selected handler to navigation view
    var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
    navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;

    // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar
    var drawerToggle = new Android_Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.open_drawer, Resource.String.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.SyncState();
}
```

I get the following error:  Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

I have tried moving the elements in the Drawerlayout but the error is persistent. I have looked at the Android documentation everything seems correct. I have also checked that I have the most recent version of both the Design and AppCompact library

Comment: It May help you https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare, Download this project and Run, Follow the same approach and alter the code as per your requirement.Hope This will help u.

Comment: Try doing a clean and rebuild to see if that fixes it. I get an error similar to this occasionally after making changes that required the Resources to be regenerated. After a rebuild, it goes away for me.

Comment: a clean and rebuild do not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: A clean and rebuild worked for me.

Comment: Can you post your `@menu/drawer_view`?

Comment: Clean + Build worked for me too.

Comment: Yep Clean+Build worked for me too. Yeah F that! Xamarin, please fix for next build :)

Answer (score 30):

I was facing the same problem some time back, I don't know exactly what caused it, but I can tell you what I did, maybe it can help you.

1. My phone memory was almost full, so I deleted some apps
2. I uninstalled the app which was giving the error
3. I cleaned and rebuilt the project
4. Ran it again.

Voila! It worked.

Comment: Are you seriously sure that this exception gets thrown because of low memory? And that it can be fixed up uninstalling few apps?

Comment: It worked with me, I never said it was the correct answer

Comment: This worked for me too, but my guess is only step 3 fixed the problem. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: yeah! i spend a day in googling and I am wondering, it worked for me as well.

Comment: #3 for me as well

Comment: #3 for me too. Strangely it was specifically a Clean and then a Rebuild. Clean + Debug didn't work, neither did Clean + Build. Thanks.

Comment: Is there no better solution than this? I get this problem 3-4 times a day. Clean Build seems to only fix it for a short time.

Comment: #2 was the fix for me

Answer (score 7):

I may be late, but i just got the same error. So on AndroidStudio, i just cleaned my project ("**Clean Projet**"). After that i was able to run my project once again without that error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you might be extending your `MainActivity` by `Activity` instead of `AppComptActivity`

If you are using any of the Design Library components, you should ensure your activity extends [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) and uses an appropriate Theme.AppCompat theme. Note that the `FloatingActionButton` relies on the `colorAccent` set on your theme - ensure your theme has that defined.

Answer (score 1):

I try my solution and it did running success:
 1. Clear temp on disk C(disk setup opera system)
 2. Rebuild project
 3. Insert in to head activity 
     [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
    public class viewDetailsActivity : BaseActivity
    {.....}
 4. Running Project
Note: insert file style.xml this code

```
     <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated-
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

    <!-- Option to hide the drop shadow here

      <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    -->
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Both of these are needed -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <!-- remove shadow below action bar -->
    <!-- <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item> -->
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/pictonBlue</item>
  </style>
```

I think i talk English not good, but problem solve success

Answer (score 1):

A quick remark regarding the exception: The exception occurs also if no content layout has been added to the `DrawerLayout`, so be sure to add one.

An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Start of content -->
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- End of content -->

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigation_view"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_activity_main_navigation" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete everything in your project's **bin** folder.
2. Delete everything in your project's **obj** folder.
3. Run Build->Clean Solution
4. Then try to build and run your solution again.

Just cleaning the solution wasn't enough for me; I had to manually remove everything in the **bin** and **obj** folders to get up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. All I needed to do was Right click on my Android solution → Properties → Android Options → set Linking to None.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by right clicking android project -> Properties -> Android Options and selecting nothing at the Code shrinker.